# Why aren't my props available to use in my component when I need them?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I keep running into similar issues like this, so I must not fully understand the lifecycle of React. I've read a lot about it, but still, can't quite figure out the workflow in my own examples.

I am trying to use props in a child component, but when I reference them using `this.props.item`, I get an issue that the props are `undefined`. However, if the app loads and then I use the React Browser tools, I can see that my component did in fact get the props.

I've tried using `componentDidMount` and `shouldComponentUpdate` in order to receive the props, but I still can't seem to use props. It always just says `undefined`.

Is there something I'm missing in React that will allow me to better use props/state in child components? Here's my code to better illustrate the issue:

```
class Dashboard extends Component {
  state = { reviews: [] }

  componentDidMount () {
   let url = 'example.com'
   axios.get(url)
   .then(res => {
     this.setState({reviews: res.data })
   })
   } 

  render() {
   return(
    <div>
     <TopReviews reviews={this.state.reviews} /> 
    </div>
   );
  }
 }

 export default Dashboard;
```

And then my `TopReviews` component:

```
class TopReviews extends Component {

state = { sortedReviews: []}

componentDidMount = () => {
 if (this.props.reviews.length > 0) {
  this.sortArr(this.props.reviews)
   } else {
    return <Loader />
   }
  }

sortArr = (reviews) => {
  let sortedReviews = reviews.sort(function(a,b){return b-a});
  this.setState({sortedReviews})
 }

render() {
 return (
  <div>
    {console.log(this.state.sortedReviews)}
  </div>
  );
 }
}

export default TopReviews;
```

I'm wanting my `console.log` to output the `sortedReviews` state, but it can never actually setState because props are undefined at that point in my code. However, props are there after everything loads.

Obviously I'm new to React, so any guidance is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you consoled your axios' response? Is it updating the parent state accordingly?

Comment: Yes, the response is good. And I have the data being used in another component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React renders your component multiple times. So you probably see an error when it is rendered first and the props aren't filled yet. Then it re-renders once they are there.

The easy fix for this would be to conditionally render the content, like

```
<div>
 { this.props.something ? { this.props.something} : null }
</div>
```

I would also try and avoid tapping into the react lifecycle callbacks. You can always sort before render, like `<div>{this.props.something ? sort(this.props.something) : null}</div>`

`componentDidMount` is also very early, try `componentDidUpdate`. But even there, make your that your props are present.

For reference: see [react's component documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html)

Comment: So I when I do this though, it puts me in an infinite loop because it keeps going back and forth between `render` and my `sort` function.

Comment: yes, because a state change will trigger a re-render. Don't do that. Unless your dataset is HUGE, you can `sort` inline and just output/render the stuff, no need to store it in the component state.

Comment: Ok, that does make sense and I got it to work. So basically I'm just saying if the props is there, run that function. If not, do nothing? How does it know to keep going until props is there? Does that make sense?

Comment: haha, that's react magic. If you want to dig into it add a `componentDidUpdate` callback and let it do a `console.log(this.props)`. This should give you some insight. React will only re-render the component if there is a change worth re-rendering, i.e. changed state or props.